# Seeking a japanese native sounding name from chinese name 陳翔榮(陈翔荣）(Chén Xíangróng)

Tags: kanji, names

Can you change my chinese name 陳翔榮(陈翔荣）(Chén Xíangróng) to a japanese name sounding like a native japanese? Many people said it would be Chin Shōei by using a method to read chinese word. I prefer to read as a japanese native sound. Help me guys!

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/21657)

Answer (score 2):

My Japanese teachers, one Chinese and one native Japanese, used 音読み to call our Chinese names.  音読み may be close to pronunciation of Chinese characters from Tang to Sung Dynasties.

You may keep using

> 陳{ちん} 翔{しょう} 榮{えい}

which is what suggested by people you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

It would be hard.  The "native" Japanese language didn't/doesn't have ん (n, ng) except for special cases.  Most instances of the ん sound in the Japanese language came from China to pronounce Chinese characters, or occur, today, to pronounce Western words.

The closest sounding Japanese pronunciation of your name would be 「チェン シャン ロン」 but it decidedly sounds Chinese, not native Japanese.

To make it sound like a native Japanese word, we would have to get rid of the ン's.  Perhaps「チェシャロ」 or 「チシャロ」?

But, I would suggest that you explore "translating" your name, instead, using the meanings, not sounds, of the Chinese characters.